# Put method into a buffer in C++

Tags: c++, concurrency, buffer, producer-consumer

I have created this method to put some data in a buffer:

```
template <typename T>
void locked_buffer<T>::put(const T & x, bool last) noexcept
{
  using namespace std;
  unique_lock<mutex> l{mut_};
  not_full_.wait(l, [this] { return !do_full(); });
  buf_[next_write_] = item{last,x};
  next_write_ = next_position(next_write_);
  l.unlock();
  not_empty_.notify_one();
}
```

But, trying to put data which consists in a return of a function:

```
int size_b;
locked_buffer<long buf1{size_b}>;
buf1.put(image, true); //image is the return of the function
```

I've got problems with the boolean variable `bool last`because I've got compilation errors.

Thanks.

Edit:
The error that I obtained is the following one:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'locked_buffer<long int>::put(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>&, bool)'
```

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] including the verbatim error messages please.

Comment: I can only guess: locked_buffer<long misses the closing >

Comment: What exactly is the compilation error you're getting?

Comment: Typo ? should it be `locked_buffer<long> buf1{size_b};` ?

Comment: ok... so is it locked_buffer<long buf1{size_b}> or locked_buffer<long> buf1{size_b}?  I dont even know if the first option is even valid code to be honest.  But regardless your compiler error says you are using 2 different data types for your template class, you are creating the class to expect a long int type for T and then you are passing a different type to the method, the type to the method needs to be the same type that is used to create your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error: no matching function for call to `locked_buffer<long int>::put(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>&, bool)`

Tells you everything you need to know:

1. Your `locked_buffer` object is templated to type: `long int`
2. Your 1<sup>st</sup> argument is of type: `vector<vector<unsigned char>>`

Now we know that these 2 types must be the same from your function definition:

```
template <typename T>
void locked_buffer<T>::put(const T & x, bool last) noexcept
```

The compiler's error is correct. You'll need to either use a matching `locked_buffer` object or create a new function:

```
template <typename T, typename R>
void locked_buffer<T>::put(const R& x, bool last) noexcept
```